# Why isn't my `my` variable accessible inside a sub?

Tags: perl, scope, mason

I'm writing a Mason 1.x component page, and it's not behaving like I'm expecting.
The perlsub man page indicates that a `my` variable should be accessible inside a `sub`.  But the following code:

```
my @myOrderBy = @orderBy;
sub sortAll
{
  my $ret = 0;
  foreach my $sortStr (@myOrderBy)
  {
  }
}
```

Is giving me the error:

> Error during compilation of
>   /opt/rt4/local/plugins/RTx-Foo/html/cf/helpers/ticketQuery.ajx:
>   Variable "@myOrderBy" is not available at
>   /opt/rt4/local/plugins/RTx-Foo/html/cf/helpers/ticketQuery.ajx
>   line 206.

(line 206 is the `foreach` line)

The same code works fine in a non-Mason context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mason apparently wraps your code in a sub (like mod_perl does). That means you end up with something like

```
$ perl -we'sub { my $x; sub sortAll { $x } }'
Variable "$x" is not available at -e line 1.
```

The explanation is long as complicated, but it boils down to: Perl doesn't support nested named subs. Attempting to do so leads to weird errors.

Might I suggest you use `local our $x;` instead of `my $x;` in this situation?

Comment: or `*sortAll = sub {` instead of `sub sortAll {`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using named subs in Mason components, the namespace is shared. Use this instead:

my $sortall = sub { ... };

Answer (score -3):

`my` variables are visible only within the code block they're declared in. The `sub` is a different code block, and therefore @myOrderBy is not available within it. See http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=66677

Comment: No, that's not true. As I said above, the code works in a non-Mason context.  Also, `man perlsub` says  
`This doesn't mean that a "my" variable declared in a statically enclosing lexical scope would be invisible.  Only dynamic scopes are
       cut off.   For example, the "bumpx()" function below has access to the lexical $x variable because both the "my" and the "sub"
       occurred at the same scope, presumably file scope.

           my $x = 10;
           sub bumpx { $x++ }`